# Python Generate PDF with HTML Contents

Tags: python, django, reportlab

I want to use reportlab PDF library (community version) to generate a PDF report from MySQL table.  There is a text field which contains HTML tags (edit using Tinymce Editor) I want to include into the PDF report.  I tried but seems reportlab could not recognized those html tags so that error was produced when running the report.

My question is does it correct that html text field could not be included into the reportlab PDF to generate formatting of the output? Or is there any other solution for generate the PDF include html tags?

Thank you!

Below is the segment of my codes:

```
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from custom_app import models as data_model
from django.conf.safestring import SafeString

s = getSampleStyleSheet()
normal_style = s['Normal']

datalist = data_model.Table.objects.all()
for rec in datalist:
    row = [
       Paragraph(rec.field_a, normal_style),
       Paragraph(SafeString(rec.field_b), normal_style)
    ]
.
.
.
```

Assume field_b contains some html tags generated by tinymce editor.  When execute the above code, the error "Value Error" displayed on the line of "Paragraph(SafeString(rec.field_b), normal_style)" line.

```
(u"paraparser: syntax error: invalid attribute name alt attrMap=['height', 'src', 'valign', 'width']", '\nparagraph text u\'<para><img src="../../core/uploads/tinymce/tc_icon-2016091910361474252596.gif" alt="" width="23" height="15" /></para>\' caused exception')
```

Comment: can you add the code portion, by which you try to print out text field(which contains HTML tags) in pdf ?

Comment: I don't know if it may be an option, but you can also look at different technologies like xhtml2pdf (https://github.com/xhtml2pdf/xhtml2pdf)